# How to strip special characters from URL via htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I have an URL `https://link.de/sub/directory/•` (that is `%E2%80%A2` at the end) that should redirect to `https://link.de/sub/directory/`, hence I need to strip the character at the end.

I tried to solve it with a `RedirectMatch`:

`RedirectMatch 301 ^directory.*$ https://link.de/sub/directory/`

But I still get the `•` at the end – which is a non-existing URL and produces an error.

How can I strip it from the URL and redirect to the URL without it?

Comment: Sorry, `directory` for all…

Comment: ok try: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/(sub/directory/).+$ /$1`

Comment: @anubhava Mind posting that as the answer? It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating my comment to answer.

You can use this `RedirectMatch` rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(sub/directory/).+$ /$1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the issue here... You can simply "ignore" anything after the prefix you are interested in:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?sub/directory/ https://example.com/sub/folder/ [R=301,L]
```

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).